# “ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified”

Tags: c#, oracle, tnsnames, tns

I know this questions with title like these are common, but I couldnt find solution on these and my question is bit different.

I'm trying to use login authenification via database via VPN. Oracle SQL Developer can connect perfectly using TNS, but c# app cant and I am getting this error (cant check if this is right error number right now, but problem is still same, I will check it tomorrow). I cant share login data from job, so any ideas what can be wrong are welcome.

Edit: I forgot to mention, I have seen just the bit of implementation, but we were trying to try connection via odbc and it didnt work either, just oracle sql developer was able to connect

Comment: Please edit the question and include information regarding the specific error you're encountering. Without more information there's really not much anyone can do to help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the old System.Data.OracleClient or ODP.NET Managed or Unmanaged?

Comment: Thats a good question. Im sorry that I cant answer now, I saw only just a bit of implementation. But i forgot to mention one detail (i will edit). We were trying to try connection via odbc and it didnt work either, just oracle sql developer was able to connect

Comment: It looks like we had been using managed version, but now we changednto unmanaged, but no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in tsnnames.ora, some magic characters appeared somewhere